# how to save a csv file in Processing for Android?

Tags: android, processing, csv

For the life of me, I cannot seem to write a simple tsv file on Android 4.2.2 using Processing for Android.

This code simply fails silently...

```
try {
  saveTable(tsv,"data.tsv");
}
catch (Exception e) {  
  println(e);
}
```

I have set the permission: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but this made no difference.

I am going crazy!!
Thanks for any help!

Bob

Comment: so it doesn't print any exception? try calling e.printStackTrace()

Comment: check out my solution below, I've given up with this.  I am more and more disappointed with querkiness of Processing. I'm used to programming in solid serious envts like Python, Lisp, C, where the reference works are *really* references...unlike Processing where the examples on processing.org are incomplete and don't always work...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the noise.... I found the solution finally:

1. using a terminal app on tyhe Nexus 4 (Android 4.2.2), I created a directory:

   $ mkdir /sdcard/MyStuff
2. the code should now read

   ```
   saveTable(tsv,"//sdcard/MyStuff/data.tsv");
   ```

Note the **//** before "**sdcard**" directory name - I guess that somehow makes the system consider the path as "external storage" and so it's ok!

What complexity!

Comment: maybe not really, when you try to save directly to "data.tsv", it attempts to save the file to the current directory (whichever it is, probably it's not /sdcard/MyStuff)

Comment: Yes, that may be, but I tried many different targets, eg. "/sdcard/data.tsv" , /storage/data.tsv" , "data.tsv" , "/data.tsv" ... but it's only when I discovered the leading double-slash syntax, i.e. "//sdcard/..." that it finally wrote a file that could be read later, or even seen in the terminal...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the GetExternalStorageDirectory method:

```
String basePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

then concatenate the string to match your path:

basePath += "MyStuff";

This requires that you import the Environment Class from the Android SDK:

```
import android.os.Environment;
```

Also, in Processing, you can just use the 'sdcard' nomenclature - ie.:

basePath = "//sdcard//MyStuff";

Answer (score 1):

Also, a related answer about making a directory with terminal - here is how you would do it from Processing:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

String dirName;

  // Create Directory
  try{
    dirName = "//sdcard//MyStuff";  // Or use te Environment Class -- see above
    File newFile = new File(dirName);
    newFile.mkdirs();
    if(newFile.exists()) {
      //
      if(newFile.isDirectory()) {
        //
      } 
      else {

      }
    } 
    else {
      println("Directory Doesn't Exist... Creating");
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

This way your code knows about the path automatically... Hope that helps!

Comment: Indeed, that helps alot!  I found all sorts of stuff in that directory!!  By the way, are the std Unix cmds not all available on the Android terminal, eg 'more', 'find', etc. ?

Comment: not sure, haven't really played with the Terminal properly... (also, if that answer helps, pls upvote! ;-) )